# How to draw on pdf page with PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I’m currently working on a project and I need to generate a PDF based on a bunch of information the user had entered.

I'm using PDFKit, I managed to create a PDFView and add a PDFDocument to it. My problem is that I couldn't really find a way to draw on the document's pages using PDFKit. I don't want to add annotations, I want to draw tables and texts inside that table's cells.

I've found some examples to do that but all of them were not complete and you need to have some knowledge to really understand them. I've also found some examples using Quartz and Core Graphics but I don't know if I can apply it to PDFKit.

I need only an example of drawing a line using PDFKit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. All you need is create pdfData:

   ```
   -(NSMutableData *)createPDFData {
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte   array
       NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

   // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
   CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(bounds, nil);

   CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   [self drawBottomRect];

   [self drawImageView:self.ivBackground];

   // draw labels by section

   [self drawLabel:self.walletName];

   currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

   // remove PDF rendering context
   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
   return pdfData;
   }
   ```
2. Example how to draw image view:

   ```
    -(void) drawImageView: (UIImageView*) imageView
    {
     CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     CGRect frameRect =  [imageView convertRect:imageView.bounds  toView:self];

     CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, frameRect.origin.x,frameRect.origin.y);
     [imageView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
      CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, -frameRect.origin.x,-   frameRect.origin.y);
    }
   ```
3. Save  PDF data as file.